# In C#, is there a way to simulate passing a pointer (without using the unsafe keyword)

Tags: c#, pointers, unsafe

Without using the 'Unsafe' keyword, can the following be accomplished:

Having a field passed as a parameter to a function. The function could periodically change the value of that field.

so if I have:

```
int MyField;
```

and:

```
MyFunction(ref MyField)
```

the function could store a pointer to `MyField` and change its value as needed.

In C++, we'd just pass a pointer to the value and then change it as needed, but I'm trying to find out if this can be accomplished in C#. I'm guessing it can be done through reflection.

Comment: That's a popular way to corrupt the heap in C++ code.  Keep writing through the pointer but have the object it points to released.  Fundamentally *unsafe*.  Simply pass a reference to the object in C# code.

Comment: also, don't try and be a C++ programmer in C#, it leads to tears

Answer (score 10):

Let me rephrase that question:

> Can I pass a reference to a variable as a parameter to a method which stores the reference so that my code can later update the variable?

No.

In the CLR type system references to variables may be *passed as formal parameters*. They may also be *returned from method calls* and *stored in local variables that are known to be of short lifetime*.  (C# does not support the latter two features; see my article on the subject for details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/23/ref-returns-and-ref-locals.aspx.)

However, they cannot be stored in fields or arrays.  In brief, references to variables may only be stored in locations that are known to be short-lived.

The reason for this restriction is because **you cannot have all four of these desirable qualities at the same time**:

- Any variable can be passed by reference
- It is always safe to access a reference to a variable (in safe code; if the variable is a pointer dereference from unsafe code then *you* are responsible for ensuring its safety, not the runtime.)
- Short-lived variables can be cleaned up without garbage collection (that is, by "popping the stack" or reusing registers, or whatever other non-gc-based storage reclaimation system is being used for the short-term storage pool.)
- Variable references can be stored in long-term storage locations

One of those has got to give, and the CLR designers chose the last one as the one that loses. The designers of C and C++ chose the second one as the one that loses.

> I'm guessing it can be done through reflection.

It cannot. But it can be done with delegates.

```
class C
{
    private Action<int> setter;
    public void RecordSetter(Action<int> setter)
    {
        this.setter = setter;
    }
    public void SetIt(int x)
    {
        this.setter(x);
    }
}
```

and now you can say:

```
class D
{
    int myField;
    void M()
    {
        C c = new C();
        c.RecordSetter(x=>{myField = x; });
        c.SetIt(123);
        Console.WriteLine(myField);
    }
}
```

The garbage collector will ensure that the instance of D stays alive as long as the instance of C stays alive.

Answer (score 6):

You're essentially doing just that by using a reference parameter (you're passing a reference...the pointer...rather than the value itself).

Comment: I think the relevant bit is "store a pointer to MyField and change its value as needed". And you can't store managed reference for later use, since you can't put it in a field.

Answer (score 2):

The use of the ref keyword is designed explicitly to prevent code from doing what I think you're asking for (i.e. being able to have a function cause the modification of the storage location passed via 'ref' parameter after it exits).  If you wish to allow code to promiscuously persist and pass around modifiable references to something, make it a public field in a wrapper object, or instantiate a single-element array and pass that around.

Answer (score 0):

By using the [Ref parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) you are passing a reference to the MyField

Comment: However, it is not possible to store this ref and then continue to use it outside the scope of the method.

Comment: @perfectionist True but I don't think that is what the OP was asking.

Answer (score 0):

No....you can't store a ref....

But you can wrap it in a class and store a reference to that.